# Having issues with file associations in Win 7

Tags: windows-7, file-association

I am trying to link a file type to an app and it's not working. The file type does not show up in the list of known file types and when I go to "Open With" it does not save the app. This issue is not system wide and only happens with an EU's profile.

Comment: Which file type and app? "does not save the app" - Did you remember to select the checkbox to set the app as default? What's EU?

Comment: EU = End User the files type is a .sgm and the app is Multi-Edit

Answer (score 0):

All information on associated file types is stored in the registry under the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT Key, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475(v=vs.85).aspx).

So your file type has to be there, or the association will not work.
If you don't see your file type under this reg key, something is wrong.

Comment: The file type is not there on a working machine, .sgm and .sgml dont show up yet I can right click on the file and do a open with and it will open the application.The laptop I am trying to fix I am unable to do that under a users profile but if I log in as my self I can do it.